# Changing a column type and keeping the data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a sql server 2005 database where one of the columns is an int. The database is full of data so I can't lose any of the data.

I need to change the the of the column from an int to a varchar(50) but this column is used in a lot of stored procedures where they are assigned to variables as int.

I want this column to store varchar now so how would I be able to do this?

Comment: Why don't you use a *different* column to store strings instead of mixing two clearly different types of data in a single column?

Comment: @AaronBertrand because there is an application that depends on that column and I'm not familiar with it. I know that all of the data stored in this column is at max 3 characters long.

Comment: So what exactly has changed in the application that now requires you to store strings when previously it only stored ints?

Comment: Altering the table is easy int to varchar is easy. The procs, well you are stuffed. Why was it an int and why is it now. Event if the data is readily convertible to int, leaving a hole like that in your DB, would be a very bad idea. You go any indexes on this column? Performance of int versus varchar50 is a bit different.

Comment: The reason for needing to change is because we getting new data from another source and the format it comes in at is different. I have no idea why it was an int before but I assume it was because that'd all they thought we'll be getting

Comment: I think you're basically screwed here. Your existing app can't handle your new data. Changing the data type of the field going to be hard, since any stored proc, view, or application that treats that field like an int will suddenly throw an error.  Even if you fix the DB (if you even can), will your application declare a variable an int and then try to assign that now-varchar field to that int variable in the app? That's a type conversion error. You're looking at either refactoring your application, or changing what data you insert into that field from your new source.